# How to display real time characters count using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please check my code below. I want to display input characters number real time using jquery javascript. But problem is when i am doing it with "textarea" it works but when i do same with normal input type text its not work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>

<!-- Works  -->

<!-- <textarea></textarea>
<span id="characters"><span>

    <script type='text/javascript'>
        $('textarea').keyup(updateCount);
        $('textarea').keydown(updateCount);

        function updateCount() {
            var cs = $(this).val().length;
            $('#characters').text(cs);
        }
    </script> -->

<!-- Not works -->

<input type="text" name="name">
<span id="characters"><span>

<script type='text/javascript'>
        $('text').keyup(updateCount);
        $('text').keydown(updateCount);

        function updateCount() {
            var cs = $(this).val().length;
            $('#characters').text(cs);
        }
 </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `text` is not a valid selector.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a working fiddle with combining your two events `keyup` and `keydown` into **one line** :-)

Your selector was wrong, `text` doesn't exist. So I call `input[name="name"]` instead to get the input by your `name` value:

```js
$('input[name="name"]').on('keyup keydown', updateCount);

function updateCount() {
  $('#characters').text($(this).val().length);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="name">
<span id="characters"><span>
```

Answer (score 1):

With "textarea" version you are selecting "textarea" by `$('textarea').keyup(updateCount)` and
        `$('textarea').keydown(updateCount)` nicely but with text input you are doing wrong to select input text.

I have fix it by placing a id called "foo" on input text. This should be working now.

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <input type="text" id="foo" name="">
    <span id="characters"><span>
    
     <script type='text/javascript'>
            $('#foo').keyup(updateCount);
            $('#foo').keydown(updateCount);
    
            function updateCount() {
                var cs = $(this).val().length;
                $('#characters').text(cs);
            }
        </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$("input").keyup(function(){
$("#characters").text($(this).val().length);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="name">
<span id="characters"><span>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get an input with the type text you must use a selector like this

```
$('input[type="text"]').keyup(updateCount);
$('input[type="text"]').keydown(updateCount);
```

Here is a list of all [jQuery selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You are not selecting the input field here.

Try the following

```
 $('input').keyup(updateCount);
 $('input').keydown(updateCount);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/mLb41vpo/

```js
$('input[type="text"]').keyup(updateCount);

function updateCount() {
    var cs = $(this).val().length;
    $('#characters').text(cs);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="">
<span id="characters"><span>
```

Mistake was `$('text').keyup(updateCount);`, you can refer input textbox using 'text'.

It should be `$('input').keyup(updateCount);`

Answer (score 0):

Everything is correct in your code, you just need to add ":" beore your type. This will make it identify, it is input type.

Example:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
        $(':text').keyup(updateCount);
        $(':text').keydown(updateCount);

        function updateCount() {
            var cs = $(this).val().length;
            $('#characters').text(cs);
        }
 </script>
```

I changed your script only. Just find the change, you will get it.